# IIS failed to call OLEDB APIs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iis, dll, oledb

I have a website which uses OLEDB to connect to MS SQL Analysis Server Services. I use C++ to call OLEDB APIs, and build it as DLL, which is loaded into IIS and called by my website. I can successfully connect to data source by calling OLEB APIs if I run C++ module locally, but my website fails to connect to data source in IIS.
  The error message is "An error was encountered in the transport layer". According to [MSDN documents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx), it's an authentication problem. But anonymous user is allowed in data source side.
  And it's curious that my website can run normally in VS2010 built-in web server. One thing I noticed is both VS2010 built-in web server and local C++ module are running with my current use account, and IIS is running with Network Service account. So I configured IIS using my current use account according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914653/how-to-use-domain-windows-user-account-as-app-pool-identity). But IIS still cannot connect to data source.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. The identity of thread in IIS used to handle request is affected by many options according to this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302377.aspx). When impersonate is true and authentication mode is Windows, if IIS uses anonymous authentication, , the identity of thread is MACHINE\IUSR_MACHINE. This account is not trusted by data source. Use other authentication modes for IIS and login into IIS with account is trusted by data source can solve this problem